# Centralizar formulário

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tenho um formulário e preciso centraliza-lo utilizando apenas as classes oferecidas pelo `bootstrap`.

Meu formulário:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class ="span8">
                <form class="form-horizontal" style="width: 25%; margin: 0 auto;" action="index.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Senha"><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Entrar</button><p>
                    <input type= "hidden" name="entrar" value="login"><p>
                    <a href="cadastro.php" button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Cadastre-se</button></a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer centralizar sem usar o `style`, é isso?

Answer (score 1):

***Bootstrap 2.3.x***

Pelo que eu pude observar pelas classes `span` em suas `divs`você está utilizando o Boostrap 2. Antes de te responder eu recomendo seriamente que você abandone essa versão do framework por ser muito ultrapassada em minha opinião. Já existe a versão 3 do framework e a 4, que está na versão alpha e com um beta aberto.

Pra você centralizar um form como o seu basta adicionar a classe `.text-center` oferecida pelo Bootstrap na `div` que contém a classe `.span12`, observe este pequeno exemplo que eu fiz:

```css
.margintop{
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12 text-center"> <!-- Centralização do form -->
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control margintop" name="email" placeholder="Email"> <br>
                   <input type="password" class="form-control margintop" name="email" placeholder="Senha"> <br>
                   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default margintop">Entrar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```